# How to (logic or software) extract the data from Open Street Map .osm (xml) files, so I get all relevant data for a given area?

Tags: openstreetmap, extract

So I have downloaded the file for Berlin from http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany.html 
and have extracted it to 
berlin-latest.osm

And want to preprocess it for my usage and for that I want for every possible tile all data relevant for graphical output in single files.

> **What's the logic for extracting?**
>  
>   And/Or 
>   **Is there a good open source software, except those using Java?**
>  
>   And 
>   **Is software usingt the .pbf files faster because of the file format better processable?**

Comment: what's the target software or usage exactly? the *.osm* file is an *XML* family format, so technically you have everything right there...

Comment: I just want/need to preprocess it to lower cpu use. I want to use it for some online application, and after like 2 decades with the same hosting company I know one thing for sure: If I try to use the full power that is promised in the contract - be it specs for databases, cpu power, connections, functionality - it won't work. Quite some people suggested to switch to an Amazon server, and I will do this one day, as at least they seem to deliver what they promise.

Comment: Your question is too vague. What do you want to do exactly? What kind of output do you expect? There are plenty of software or solutions. Do you need a UI or does it need to run headless on a server? Do you expect to use diff files? How many kind of features do you plan to extract? A lot of questions can be raised.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. We use a "Focused question/Best answer" model, so multiple questions often result in closure as *too broad*.

Comment: As far as I know [osmium-tool](https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/) is currently the fastest tool for data processing / extraction.

Comment: @scai: Thank you for your link, too. Nearly what I was looking for. There is no explicit windows version, and the "copyright" holder doesn't want one. (I don't blame him for not liking to be involved with a windows versions - if I had switched to another OS by now I also wouldn't care about a windows version, but he probably just should put it somewhere on his website, instead of where I found it somewhere in two consecutive closed pull request, dragging the topic over 12 months and then saying 'sorry, I should have answered more recently'. Sadly Unprofessional, unreliable, therefore won'T use

Comment: That's a questionable opinion about an open source tool for which you don't pay a penny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a geographers point of view I would skip the whole XML part and would only work with the PBF. Download it and put it into [PostgreSQL with the spatial postgis extension](https://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=loading_osm_postgis). 
To work interactively with the data in the PostGIS database I would recommend using QGIS and connect to the db from there. 
Then only the sky is the limit.
There are [plenty of tutorials for QGIS](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/learning_resources.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Basically it's exactly the answer I was looking for. (And it makes me happy to see my question wasn't too vague, if the only answer fits my expectation exactly.)